# Rails 4 syntax for shoulda matchers "have_many" with "order"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I have a rails 4 validation for my User model:

`has_many :items,  -> { order(:position) }`

I expected the following shoulda matcher to work:
`it {should have_many(:items).order(:position)}`

But it raises this error:
`Expected User to have a has_many association called items (items should be ordered by position)`

Is my syntax wrong for the test?

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug in v2.4.0 where this didn't work. This has been fixed in v2.5.0, so check it out!

See here for more: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/388

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.

Comment: @MichaelvanHolst can you accept the answer so that others see this?